# SQL query in SQL Server 2008 - grouping and sorting

Tags: sql-server-2008, sorting, grouping

I'm looking for SQL query for a problem that I have.

I have 2 columns - the first is "employee full name" (containing FULL name) and the second is "Hours".

```
Employee Full Name | Hours | grading
-------------------------------------
john ran             122
john medi            177
john mat             138
jack rom             66
jack ton             88
```

I would like to update the database with the "grading" column in the following way:

grouping employees by their FIRST name, and then grading them (in ascending order) by working hours (highest working hours for employee with a specific first name) gets grade of 1, second 2, etc...).

The result should be like this:

```
Employee Full Name | Hours | grading
------------------------------------
john ran             122      3
john medi            177      1
john mat             138      2
jack rom             66       2
jack ton             88       1
```

There are no 2 employees with the same full name

Comment: It is best to describe your database structure in http://sqlfiddle.com. We can then more easily work out a solution for you.

Comment: Employee first ans last name are not in diffrent columns? That would make your life eazier.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be ranking employees by their first name?  This seems extremely arbitrary.  In your example, "jack ton" has a better ranking than "john mat" despite working more hours.  Also, are you sure all names are "first last"?  What about "first"?  Or "first m last"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` to perform this update using `row_number()`

```
;with cte as
(
  select *,
    row_number() 
      over(partition by substring([EMPLOYEE FULL NAME], 1, charindex(' ', [EMPLOYEE FULL NAME])) 
           order by hours desc) rn
  from yourtable
)
update cte
set grading = rn;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a411/11)

Ideally, you will want to normalize your database to have the first and last name in separate columns.